# « Vive » ou « vivent » les vacances ?

Tags: usage, subjonctif, interjections

Dois-je dire « vive les vacances » ou bien « vivent les vacances » ?

C'est un subjonctif présent du verbe vivre, donc je pencherais pour le deuxième. Mais j'ai peur que l'usage soit davantage en faveur du premier…

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Extrait du [site de l'académie française](http://www.academie-francaise.fr/la-langue-francaise/questions-de-langue#90_strong-em-vive-les-vacances-ou-vivent-les-vacances-em-strong) :

> D’un point de vue grammatical, la phrase *Vive(nt) les vacances* peut être analysée comme une indépendante au subjonctif exprimant un souhait et comparée à une phrase du type *Périssent les traîtres !* Le verbe s’accordera donc naturellement avec son sujet et l’on pourra écrire *Vivent les vacances*. Cependant *vive* est aujourd’hui perçu plus souvent comme un simple mot exclamatif que comme un verbe traduisant un véritable souhait de longue existence, ce qui explique que ce terme tende à perdre sa valeur verbale et qu’on puisse le considérer comme une particule à valeur prépositionnelle : on le rencontre par conséquent fréquemment au singulier.
>
> On a parfois voulu distinguer deux cas : les noms de personnes, véritablement douées de vie, qui exigeraient l’accord (*Vivent les mariés*), et les noms de choses, avec lesquels le verbe resterait invariable (*Vive les sports d’hiver*). L’usage littéraire contredit cette volonté et l’on trouve, indifféremment avec les personnes comme avec les choses, l’accord et l’invariabilité, comme c’était déjà le cas en latin où l’on pouvait rencontrer *vivat* et *vivant*.

Comment: Merci de respecter l'italique dans les citations. C'est difficilement lisible autrement.

Answer (score 12):

À l'origine cette expression se trouvait sous la forme « Que vivent les vacances ! », où là, clairement il s'agit du verbe vivre qui doit s'accorder.
Au fil du temps, le *que* a disparu.

On se retrouve donc avec une expression où l'on peut interpréter le *vive* tantôt comme le verbe *vivre*, tantôt comme une interjection : *vive* qui du coup ne s'accorde pas.
Les deux formes sont donc [admises](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/vive%C2%A0_/82306/difficulte) (avec une préférence pour la forme interjective) :

> Vive les vacances !
>
> Vivent les vacances !

Le NGram semble montrer cette évolution au fil du temps :

[image: Vive les, Vivent les]