# Comprehension problem: inversion and pronoun meaning

Tags: sens, pronoms, constructions

I'm translating a passage of a book concerning Quebec French and I've stumbled on a construction I don't understand (in bold, the rest is the context):

> En soi le québécisme devrait constituer la solution idéale pour nommer ce qui émane d'ici. [...] Or il semble en régression, moins d'usage aujourd'hui qu'hier, plus rare en ville qu'à la campagne. **Allons-nous à l'extérieur que nous redoutons de n'être pas entendus.** Une fois l'expression française de remplacement apprise ou réactualisée, autant faire disparaître la formule synonymique du cru.

Is there an inversion here because it's the imperative? Is *que* a relative pronoun referring to *l'extérieur*? Could anybody translate or paraphrase it for me into English?

[image]

Comment: After reading it several times here is approximatively what happened in my head "I got it", "hum ... no", "oh yes !", "well ... no", "that must be from pipotron" http://www.pipotron.free.fr/

Comment: Some more context would certainly help, it's really difficult to understand the intended meaning of these sentences without an access to the broader picture.

Comment: I scanned the whole page. Maybe that will help by adding more context. It is the book "Récits d'une passion" by Gilles Pellerin.

Comment: @hoang pipotron ? oh my god, how old is this... Check the [latest technology](http://romainvaleri.online.fr/) in the field... ;-)

Comment: @RomainVALERI you should rename your tool to something more meaningful. Plus it is less usable in a business context, whereas pipotron really produce sentences that go like clockwork.

Comment: We must have different meanings for the word *meaningful* ;-) But nevermind, go on pipotroning...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that's the usual¹ contraction of the seldom found form “*alors que*”, meaning² “while”. From the Wiktionary :

> ***Alors que** : (Vieilli) Synonyme de* lorsque, *dans le sens de* au moment de.
>   *Alors que* je mangeais, le téléphone a sonné.

So this sentence could be rephrased into :

> *Nous redoutons de n'être pas entendus* alors que *nous allons à l'extérieur.*

Meaning something like :

> *When* we go outside, we fear not to be heared/understood.

---

¹ I think nowadays, being said it's very uncommon, it's more often contracted than not (the full form sounds old, the short one doesn't).
² “*Alors que*” is a lot more often used to say “whereas” — especially in oral speech.

Comment: La réponse est excellente (+1), j'ajouterais simplement ceci : la forme présente dans l'extrait semble un peu étrange (notamment en France et dans un contexte oral), mais le serait beaucoup moins en ajoutant simplement *A peine* ou *Aussitôt* en tête de phrase.

Comment: Je suis d'accord que le passage est très littéraire (à commencer par l'inversion *n'être pas* pour *ne pas être*). Par contre, il me semble qu'ajouter une telle tête de phrase — outre que ça en rendrait l'expression beaucoup plus usuelle, tu as raison — en modifierait le sens : en l'état, tout le temps où nous allons à l'extérieur, nous le redoutons. Avec la modification, on redoute **dès** qu'on va à l'extérieur, mais « c'est tout ». L'emphase n'est pas mise au même endroit (*moment*, en fait).

Comment: Oui, je reconnais très volontiers la nuance de sens. Ce n'était que pour rendre la forme moins *étrange* en la rapprochant d'une autre, grammaticalement très proche, et plus usuelle.

Comment: Ah, now I got your interpretation right. You mean “dès que” not “alors que”. It's indeed another possibility… and probably the right guess.

Comment: Merci, Nikana Reklawyks. Après un moment de réflexion je comprends cette interprétation dans le context donné. Toujours, je voudrais apprendre quelle est la valeur de l'inversion ici. Est-ce une figure de style tout simplement?

Comment: @ghul : Je ne sais trop qu'ajouter à l'observation du style hautement recherché de l'écrivain. Je ne sais pas quelle figure de style il faudrait y voir, d'après moi, c'est simplement une tournure aux franges de la désuétude, certes là du plus bel effet. Avec d'autres exemples, la question de savoir ce que ça apporte au texte peut-être intéressante, maintenant que — si on est tous d'accord — on sait ce que ça veut dire.

Comment: Did you mean "a usual contraction" or "an unusual contraction" of « ... alors que ... » ? Ceci dit, je me demande si "aller à l'extérieur" a un double sense.

Comment: @AlexisWilke : I meant an *usual* contraction, as is written. *Alors que* is seldom found, but when it's used, it's often abreviated into *que* no more. I think. I edited to make it clearer, maybe.

Comment: The thing is you don't say "an university" and you don't say "an usual" either. "an" is not used for words that start with a "u". « Alors qu'il me fit un remarque sur mon anglais, je ne compris pas. »

Comment: @AlexisWilke: Oh, right, I didn't realize the *u* didn't sound the same in both words, so put it because it's there in *an unusual …* Thanks a lot ! (« *une* remarque » et « deux *sens* » ;)

Answer (score 2):

This is an unusual sentence construction. It is recognizable, but at least in France sounds somewhat affected, even in writing (I don't know if it's any different in Québec).

I understand the meaning, but I don't know the name of this construction.

The meaning is roughly equivalent to *Dès que nous allons à l'extérieur, nous redoutons de n'être pas entendus* or *à peine allons-nous à l'extérieur que nous redoutons de n'être pas entendus*. With *à peine*, putting the subject after the verb is standard written French (see [*Inversion du sujet avec peut-être* in the *Banque de dépannage linguistique*](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?Th=2&t1=&id=3472).). Here is [another contemporary example](http://crbalma.fr/index.php?option=com_docman&task=doc_download&gid=127&Itemid=59):

> Nos 4 aventuriers/Vétetistes n'étaient-ils pas encore parti vers le Portugal que déjà se présentait la première difficulté

(The highbrow construction of the opening sentence contrasts with the resolutely informal language of the rest of the article.)

There's probably no perfect translation for that kind of language quirk. Something like “should we venture outside, we fear not being heard” or “were we to venture outside, we fear remaining unheard” should be in the right ballpark.

Comment: Vive([nt](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/3291/vive-ou-vivent-les-vacances)) les citations qui contiennent des fautes d'orthographe ! (ou pas…)

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez C'est la seule citation que j'ai réussi à trouver. Je n'ai pas de bon moyen de chercher cette construction syntaxique. Si tu as mieux, je suis preneur.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that we have what Grevisse described as *pseudo-propositions* (*Le Bon Usage*, 12<sup>ième</sup> édition, §1067):

> Lorsque des sous-phrases sont coordonnées d'une manière implicite, il y a entre elles une liaison logique. La langue semble ne pas se satisfaire de cette absence de lien visible, et elle tend à le marquer au moyen de la conjonction *que*, ce qui a souvent pour effet d'inverser la hiérarchie logique : la sous-phrase devenue proposition par l'introduction du *que* est souvent la partie la plus importante du message.

And he gives examples in several contexts, some of the more pertinent for this question:

> *J'étais gamine,* QU'*elle achetait déjà des navets à mon père.* (Zola, *Ventre de P.*, I) — *Tout s'était envolé* QUE *les Français tiraient toujours.* (Barrès, *Union sacrée*, p. 216) — *Le diable entrerait dans la maison* QU'*on le laisserait faire* (Hugo, *Misér.*, I, I, 9). [...]

Edit: I forgot the first part of the question.  It's an inversion of the subject and the verb (it isn't an imperative, the subject would be absent). That may occur in French in a few more situations than for questions.  There are about ten pages on the subject in the *Bon Usage*, the relevant case here is the one of verbs expressing movement such as *entrer*, *passer*, *arriver*, ... one situation where it is done nearly systematically is in stage directions.

Answer (score -5):

It seems to have the sense of a question So why not translating it with

> Do we go outside fearing not be listened ?

Comment: I'm afraid it has not.

Comment: No, not a question here, although the reverse form (verbal group first) is quite misleading. Besides, *listened* would be a translation of *écoutés* rather than *entendus* (the word you searched for may be *heard*)

Comment: I would say *understood* and not *heard* :-)

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Agreed on this one. But definitely not *listened*.

Comment: @Romain VALERI : you're right. "*Listened*" is too strong. "*Heard*" and "*understood*" are more convinient.